# Nginx get index.html always from cache

Tags: caching, nginx, time

Hello I'm trying to configure a nginx cache system. 
This is my configuration file

```
proxy_cache_valid 200 1m;
proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
add_header Cache-Control public;
add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
proxy_cache my_cache;
proxy_pass http://myurl;
```

All works good. If I look at headers request :

```
X-cache-status : HIT;
```

But if for example I change my index.html and make another request the old one is shown.

I think I'm missing something for this configuration. There is some other configuration for getting best performance from nginx cache?
Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: What's the expiry time on index.html? It will serve the old version until its expired.

Comment: @FaisalMemon there is something I can't get. What if for example there are dynamic content, let's say an home page with a lot of post. In this case older homepage with less posts will be shown ? Or home page will be updated with the new post? Thanks

Comment: If the version currently in the cache has not expired, then it will serve the version in the cache.

Comment: @FaisalMemon there is some mechanism that can purge some data into the cache ? For example when there are new posts purge the old version of the home page

Comment: There is a 3rd party module: https://github.com/FRiCKLE/ngx_cache_purge.  Alternatively you can delete the files in your cache directory.